# PL/SQL REGEXP_LIKE with multiple [0-9][0-9]

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I am having a hard time making my PL/SQL code work. I have a constraint that makes sure 5 digits have been input. The constraint works for any number that does not use a 0 first. Example 0, 1, 2, 33, 401 work but 01, 02, 004 do not work. How can I make it so that I can input numbers such as 00009?

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
 id NUMBER(5)
    CONSTRAINT idconstraint
        CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(id, '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'))
);


INSERT INTO table1
VALUES ('00009');
```

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question.

Comment: Your regexp would match `000009` as well. This one may suit better: `'^[0-9]{5}$'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the wrong constraint or the wrong data type.  If you want leading zeros, use `varchar2()` or `char()`.  Because you seem to want a fixed length string, try this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id CHAR(5)
        CONSTRAINT idconstraint
            CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(id, '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'))
);
```

Your problem is that the field is declared as a number.  The input string is converted to a number, then back to a string.  It loses the leading `0`'s in the process.

Comment: Thank you! I have been looking for a while and thought it was somewhere in my constraint. Figures it was something so simple.